# To how list group by values and values in that category

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.10

I want my template to display my group by category as a header, and then all the values for that group by category under it. For example, my table looks like this:

```
['John','Physics']
['Jim','Physics']
['Sam','Biology']
['Sarah','Biology']
```

And I want the template to output this:

## Physics

John

Jim

## Biology

Sam

Sarah

I'm not sure what to put in my veiws.py as I would usually do this in SQL --> first group by category, then return all results in that category.

How would my veiws.py and template looks like to accomplish this? Thanks.

My current veiws.py:

```
def department(request):
students = Students.objects.all().order_by('department')
return render(request, 'department.html', {
    'students':students,
})
```

Here is my model.py

```
class Mentors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And my template:

```
{% if mentors %}
<div class="row">
    {% for mentor in mentors %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <h3>{{ mentor.department }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{ mentor.image.url }}" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4 class="text-center">{{ mentor.name }}, {{ mentor.degree }}</h4>
                        <p class="text-center"><small>{{ mentor.department }}</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor%}
</div><!-- /.end row -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How does your current template look?

Comment: can you post your model ?

Comment: @levi 
Here is my model: 
class Mentors(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 degree = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Comment: @user2453757 I mean, Student Model.

Comment: class Student(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template (department.html) is the place where you're going to list all the student. You must have some similar to this:

```
{% if students %}
    {% for student in students %}
        <p>{{ student.NAME_FIELD }}</p>
        {{ student.DEPARTMENT_FIELD}}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    No student are available.
{% endif %}
```

NAME_FIELD and DEPARTMENT_FIELD are the fields you declared in your model.py

Comment: This is listing every DEPARTMENT_FIELD for each NAME_FIELD. I would like to only list the DEPARTMENT_FIELD once and then list the NAME_FIELD under it.

Comment: What you can do is to send within your response, the list of departments. Like you did with student, try something like this. list_departments = Students.objects.values('department').distinct('department') --- then for each department in your template, you list the students that belong to one of them.

Comment: How do I do that in my template? I thought you can not run QuerySets in your template files?

Comment: In your view, you list all departments that you have, using this: list_departments = Students.objects.values('department').distinct('department'), like you did for Students. Then, you send it within your request: return render(request, 'department.html', {
    'students':students, 'list_departments':list_departments,
}). Now, you have two variable, students and list_department in your template, and you can loop through the list_department. For each department, you loop through the students and check which ones belongs to this department.

Comment: you can delete each student that you find for a certain department. Then, the list will decrease.